# How to Rectify "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component". (React Class Component)

Tags: reactjs, express, sockets, error-handling, setstate

So the challenge is this, I am trying to add a new game room whenever the current one is full and update the **gameId** state variable, this should happen when the **addNewRoom** event is triggered.

Whenever **addNEwRoom** comes into effect however I get an error in the browser's console as can be seen in the image
[Error from browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN8GH.png)

> Below is the block from which the issue appears to originate

```
socket.on("addNewRoom", (theroomId) => {
  console.log(theroomId.rm);
  socket.emit("createNewGame", theroomId.rm + "1");
  this.setState({
    gameId: theroomId.rm + "1",
  });
});
```

Initially I had the **addNewRoom** event inside of the  **sendJoinTournament** arrow function.
After seeing the error and did some research I added that block of code inside **componentDidMount()** as you will be seeing in the full code posted below. This is from a react project I found on Github and decided to modify for learning purposes as I am still a newbie, any insight or assistance would be highly appreciated.

**Onboard.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import uuid from "uuid/v4";
import { ColorContext } from "../context/colorcontext";
const socket = require("../connection/socket").socket;

/**
 * Onboard is where we create the game room.
 */

class CreateNewGame extends React.Component {
  state = {
    didGetUserName: false,
    inputText: "",
    gameId: "",
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textArea = React.createRef();
    this.textArea1 = React.createRef();
  }

  sendJoinTournament = () => {
    const url = document.getElementById("urlBox").value;
    const roomId = url.slice(27, 63);

    socket.emit("checkRoomSize", roomId);

    this.setState({
      gameId: roomId,
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    //if checkRoomsize indicates that room full this activates
    socket.on("addNewRoom", (theroomId) => {
      console.log(theroomId.rm);
      socket.emit("createNewGame", theroomId.rm + "1");
      this.setState({
        gameId: theroomId.rm + "1",
      });
    });
  }

  sendCreateNewGame = () => {
    /**
     * This method should create a new room in the '/' namespace
     * with a unique identifier.
     */

    const newGameRoomId = uuid();

    // set the state of this component with the gameId so that we can
    // redirect the user to that URL later.
    this.setState({
      gameId: newGameRoomId,
    });

    socket.emit("createNewGame", newGameRoomId);
  };

  typingUserName = () => {
    // grab the input text from the field from the DOM
    const typedText = this.textArea.current.value;

    // set the state with that text
    this.setState({
      inputText: typedText,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.didGetUserName ? (
          <Redirect to={"/game/" + this.state.gameId}>
            <button
              className="btn btn-success"
              style={{
                marginLeft: String(window.innerWidth / 2 - 60) + "px",
                width: "120px",
              }}
            >
              Start Game
            </button>
          </Redirect>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h1
              style={{
                textAlign: "center",
                marginTop: String(window.innerHeight / 3) + "px",
              }}
            >
              Your Username:
            </h1>
            <input
              style={{
                marginLeft: String(window.innerWidth / 2 - 120) + "px",
                width: "240px",
                marginTop: "62px",
              }}
              ref={this.textArea}
              onInput={this.typingUserName}
            ></input>
            <br></br>
            <input
              style={{
                marginLeft: String(window.innerWidth / 2 - 120) + "px",
                width: "10px",
                marginTop: "31px",
              }}
              type="radio"
              id="myRadio"
              name="createRadio"
              value="HTML"
              Ref={this.radiobutton1}
            ></input>
              <label for="html">Create New Game</label>
            <br></br>
            <input
              style={{
                marginLeft: String(window.innerWidth / 2 - 120) + "px",
                width: "10px",
                marginTop: "31px",
              }}
              type="radio"
              id="myRadio1"
              name="joinRadio"
              value="HTML"
              Ref={this.radiobutton2}
            ></input>
              <label for="html">Join a Game</label>
            <input
              style={{
                marginLeft: String(window.innerWidth / 2 - 120) + "px",
                width: "240px",
                marginTop: "62px",
              }}
              placeholder="paste link"
              id="urlBox"
              ref={this.textArea1}
            ></input>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              style={{
                marginLeft: String(window.innerWidth / 2 - 60) + "px",
                width: "120px",
                marginTop: "62px",
              }}
              disabled={!(this.state.inputText.length > 0)}
              onClick={() => {
                // When the 'Submit' button gets pressed from the username screen,
                // We should send a request to the server to create a new room with
                // the uuid we generate here.
                if (document.getElementById("myRadio").checked) {
                  this.props.didRedirect();
                  this.props.setUserName(this.state.inputText);
                  this.setState({
                    didGetUserName: true,
                  });
                  this.sendCreateNewGame();
                }

                if (document.getElementById("myRadio1").checked) {
                  this.sendJoinTournament();
                  this.setState({
                    didGetUserName: true,
                  });
                }
              }}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const Onboard = (props) => {
  const color = React.useContext(ColorContext);

  return (
    <CreateNewGame
      didRedirect={color.playerDidRedirect}
      setUserName={props.setUserName}
    />
  );
};

export default Onboard;
```

Comment: Hi, please  edit and carefully format your code; it's hard to read as is

Comment: Hi pierpy, thanks for letting me know. I formatted it a bit and highlighted a few key areas to assist with keeping track of what's important. If there is anything else I can do to make this easier, please let me know.